# Magento 1.9.2.4 - Place Order not go success page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.2.4

I have a problem about onepage checkout in my Magento 1.9.2.4. When i push on Place Order for send my order, Magento not go to success page but redirect to checkout page with the product again in the cart. Why this? What could be the solution?

P.S. I Update my Magento from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4.

Comment: please enable log  from track why this happen

Comment: When enabling `display_errors = 1` at .user.ini check the request output. you got to know the error reason.then you can be able tosolve this

Answer (score 2):

It probably means that when you try to create order occur unexpected error.  You could turn on display of mistake and reproduce the error, if it will create you will see it. It can do in *index.php*  at Magento root:

Change next code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

For this:

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If it is life site, will be better turn on error log in admin  *System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes* after that cheek in yet one time  (reproduce the error) and look at logs. Old logs (*var/log/system.log*, *var/log/exception.log*, and folders *var/reports*) could rename (or move).

If you will find error these ways, complete its your question and we try to help you.

Comment: can we done this  without affecting magento files

Answer (score 0):

i am also hitting checkout/onepage/success url directly after commenting all code in successAction() in OnepageController.php, but it's redirecting to checkout/cart showing empty cart.
Note:- Order saved successfully, but order success page not showing

Please provide solution for above issue.

Comment: add this as a comment and not answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar issue and found file permissions were incorrect on /lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php

I set file permissions to 644 and everything clicked back on (as well as emailing out a backlog of order notifications) Hope this helps someone else.